# Task manager in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, task-manager

Can I change **keyboard shortcut** for task manager (CTRL+ALT+DEL)
 in Windodows XP with new sequence (like:A+B)

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. However, the answer is no. Ctrl+ALt+Del is not changeable, and not easily even interceptable (you have to write a GINA DLL to do so, hooking into the login process). This is by design.

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to set password for starting task manager?

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for task manager is actually Ctrl+Shift+Esc. This works whether or not you enable the Welcome screen.